# Xamarin.Forms - Show Embedded Resource image in listview Template

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.listview

I have a list view in Xamarin.Forms and I have set ItemTemplate e.g.

```
listView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
{
  Image img = new Image();
  img.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, "ImageUrl");
  ...so on
}
```

This works if image is stored in the same project but I have moved image to PCL project and set to "Embedded Resource".

I need to state somehting like below but it doesn't work, how can I achieve this so it will bind "embedded resource" to image control in list item.

```
img.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, "ImageSource.FromResource(ImageUrl)");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created readonly property in model to return ImageSource and it still uses ImageUrl property to return ImageSource and now I just bind to this new readonly property.

```
//in model    
[JsonIgnore]
public ImageSource ImageUrlSource { get { return ImageSource.FromResource(ImageUrl); } }



listView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
{
Image img = new Image();
img.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, "ImageUrlSource"); 
...so on
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify the assembly that the image exists

```
ImageSource.FromResource("yourNamespace.imageName.png", typeof(className).GetTypeInfo().Assembly))
```